# How to left align items in itemize that contains columns environment on beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, itemize

I need to automatically left align all my `item`s. The problem is that I must have a `columns` environment in the middle. But that environment shifts the items to the left. I tried setting `\setlength{\itemindent}{0em}` to fixed the shift problem.

In some cases it works. However, is really time consuming and it doesn't work in general, as I have to constantly check if the bullets are aligned. I would like to find an automatic way of aligning them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a really long sentence that I used to demonstrate how strange it is to shift the items.
\item This is another sentence.
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
\item Test of one sentence in the column.
\item Test of another sentence in the same column.
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.3\linewidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\item Another sentence after the columns environment.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to have columns? Your columns are semantically part of the item 'This is another sentence' this way.

Comment: I was looking for a way of inserting the image in the middle of the items, as the `wrapfig` and `cutout` didn't work. This solution is easy and work without much changes. However, the alignment is off.

Comment: So not very easy and doesn't work very well because the alignment is off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another blank column on the left end of the `columns` environment.  In this case, using a column 1 width of `\leftmargini` works (that is the `itemize` indent), while columns 2 and 3 must add up to `\linewidth`.  I also added 1ex of vspace after closing the `columns` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a really long sentence that I used to demonstrate how strange it is to shift the items.
\item This is another sentence.
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{\leftmargini}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\item Test of one sentence in the column.
\item Test of another sentence in the same column.
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.3\linewidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}\vspace{1ex}
\item Another sentence after the columns environment.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`columns` environment has an optional parameter which fixes columns width

```
\begin{columns}[totalwidth=...]
```

If you don't fixes it to `\textwidth` beamer enlarges a bit line width. To avoid it use option `onlytextwidth` (equivalent to `totalwidth=\textwidth`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a really long sentence that I used to demonstrate how strange it is to shift the items.
\item This is another sentence.
\end{itemize}
%
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test of one sentence in the column.
\item Test of another sentence in the same column.
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.3\linewidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
%
\begin{itemize}
\item Another sentence after the columns environment.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]